# Find and Replace/Update links like Dreamweaver in other editors

Tags: replace, sublimetext2, dreamweaver, text-editor, macrabbit-espresso

I've been slowly weening myself off of Dreamweaver and using other editors like SublimeText and Espresso. But there are two features that are lacking in those editors that I still find the need to use Dreamweaver for:

1.) Find and Replace within entire current local site.

2.) Update links when a page is saved within another directory. For example, if you rename, or re-save a file that is open within another directory, Dreamweaver will ask you to update the links. This will then make sure that if the file is moved or saved to another directory it will update any links within the HTML for stylesheets, images, navigation, etc.

Does any know of any other apps or tools that might be able to accomplish those actions without having to crack open Dreamweaver?

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail about what #2 does and how it works?  Why do the links need updating?  Is this a page rename or what?

Answer (score 3):

The Sublime Text plugin ['Side Bar Enhancements'](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) has Search/Replace entire project functionality. Doesn't handle update links across files (that i've found)

PHPStorm may handle the second question.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I've installed the Side Bar Enhancements for ST2.